# Accessible reference on geometrisation conjecture

Tags: geometry, manifolds

Recently I bumped into playlist of 2010 Clay Research Conference. All talks are amazing, but mainly I was intrigued by two of them:

1. The evolution of geometric structures on 3-manifolds by Curtis McMullen
2. The Mystery of 3-Manifolds by William Thurston.

here are the links on the talks https://www.claymath.org/library/video-catalogue

After those talks I want to dig into the geometrisation conjecture. I am looking for relatively selfcontained acessible reference to understand the maters of geometrisation conjecture. Mainly I wish to understand 8 geometries mentioned in context of 3-manifolds in McMullen's talk and understand a relation of knots and geometries that was mentioned in both of talks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out "[The geometries of 3-manifolds](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/%7Emasgar/Teach/2012_MA4J2/geometry.pdf)", Bulletin of the London Mathematical Society (1983), by Peter Scott. He does not discuss knots though, but the paper will have more than enough material for the first reading.